# How do -~x and ~-x work?

Tags: bit-manipulation, twos-complement

I read ([here](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/blog/?p=78)) and verified (with a computer) that `-~x` is equal to `x+1` and `~-x` equal to `x-1` so I tried to write it down and see what is happening but I'm doing something wrong.

Let's take `x=4`

```
0100 // 4 in binary, leading 0 for the sign
1100 // the inverse of the addition
0011 // ~ complement
```

`0011=3` which is according to the rule `~-x === x-1`

But for `-~x` I get the same:

```
0100 // 4 in binary
1011 // ~ complement
0011 // the inverse
```

Where do I go wrong? Am I being stupid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the problem was my representation of negative numbers. I have to use the [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) operation and then it returns the correct result. So `-~x` will behave like:

```
0100 // 4 (we assume a 4 bit number without taking sign into account)
1011 // complement which is 11
```

And now using Two's complement:

> The two's complement of an N-bit number is defined as the complement
>   with respect to 2N; in other words, it is the result of subtracting
>   the number from 2N.

In this case `N=4` and `2^N = 16` and finally when we subtract 11 from 16 we get 5 which is `x+1`. We showed that `-~x === x+1`